# selenium - How to cut string by expecting what is behind/after the text- e.g given in the picture

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I'm currently trying to web crawl a website and came across a date range

e.g 開催期間：2021年4月1日 ～ 2022年3月31日（ 最終更新日：2021年04月18日 ）

How do i iterate through the text so that i can extract

"2021年4月1日 ～ 2022年3月31日" and "2021年04月18日"

I initially put it into an array and slice and diced it but because the date periods can change depending on the post date i cant use the arrays for it

I was wondering if there is a way to extract the date period upon detection of certain words or symbol

e.g start taking record after "開催期間:" until coming upto " (" resulting in 2021年4月1日 ～ 2022年3月31日

e.g Start taking record after "最終更新日：" and stop until coming upto ")" or the end of line

Hope this makes sense

E.G pic of the website currently crawling is attached below : (link is attached below) https://stamprally.org/s/25459

tried below but for some reason the .split doesnt seem to work either, i also tried the same code on online compilers and the split method doesnt work...

```
postExpireDate = (driver.find_element_by_css_selector( 'time.entry-date updated')).text.split("(").replace(開催期間：)
```

[image: Website Dates]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: How about using regex?

Comment: @klaus D sure thing, i tried something like the below, failed miserably so far

                    postExpireDate = (driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                        'time.entry-date updated')).text.split("(").replace(開催期間：)

Comment: Don't post code in the commands, add it to the question!

Comment: @Klaus D yes sir :)

Comment: @helllper your css selector is only for the second part you are looking for and it should be  `time.entry-date.updated`. To get whole line with required text use css `#post_date`

Comment: @Lia thanks for your comment, you mentioned 'it should be time.entry-date.updated' and you are indeed correct. I was under the notion that "." (dot) is used only for classes and on the website the class name is "entry date updated" with a space. would you do me a favor of letting me know how and why the "." (dot) was necessary

Comment: Right, dot is used for classes and you have two different classes under your `time` tag separated by space: `entry-date` and `updated`. It's not one class, but two classes. Here is the way to verify your selectors: https://testerlive.wordpress.com/2016/07/02/how-to-search-by-xpathcss-in-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Why two classes? - because CSS allows an HTML element to have multiple classes

Comment: @Lia, right ! I just copied the class name from the HTML in the DOM in which case it tells me "entry date updated" WITH a space But in the F12 Selector it does indeed tell me that it has a "." dot... lesson learnt :) thanks Lia